# ORDER BY in PHP/MYSQL not working

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-order-by

The sql query is

```
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY gamename" );
```

But it doesn't order them by the gamename. This is a sample of the database

```
id (int) | gamename (text) | gameurl (varchar) | width (int) | height (int)

1--------- Copter ---------- copter ----------- 100 ---------- 200--------

2--------- Adrenaline ------ adr -------------- 200 ---------- 300--------
```

Comment: So how are the results ordered? a sample of the returned list might help?

Comment: Never use an asterix in select

Comment: @Tom Gullen - Why would you say never? Never say never. What if he had a legitimate need for all the columns, that's a perfectly valid reason to do a select * vs writing out each and every column. Sure if he adds many more columns and doesn't need them all that changes, but in this case it seems perfectly acceptable. Additionally theres no user input on this query, its a generic dump of a table with a simple order clause...am I missing something in the logic?

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum: don't forget the other way around: a column which has disappeared, but that you're expecting. Not unusual when refactoring large projects. At least by specifying the columns the error would be plainly visible / show up correctly in your log.

Comment: @Wrikken - Good call. Didn't even think of that fact, funny to considering that has occurred many a time when I've taken on other developer's projects in which I am unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide us a slightly longer sample list? Also when you say it doesn't order are you trying to go ascending or descending? By default it sorts Ascending. You need to say ORDER BY gamename DESC to get it to do it descending...

Also while not required i'd advise wrapping the orderby field in an UPPER i.e. order by UPPER(gamename) so that Upper/Lower case letters are treated equally.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a space before the C in Copter?